# How to make Lombok @Data class work with Spring Data JPA projections?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, lombok

I need a class that can be used as a projection, but also be  serialized/deserialized to/from JSON.

If I create a projection class and annotate it with `@Value`, it works as a projection, but cannot be deserialized as it has no default constructor.

If I create a projection class an annotate it with `@Data`, it can be serialized/deserialized but it cannot be used as a projection. It fails with:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException:
    No converter found capable of converting from type <ENTITY> to type <PROJECTION>
```

Tried this to satisfy both:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Projection {
    private Long cdFilaClienteAlterado;
    private UUID cdCliente;
    private String nmCliente;
    private Long nrCpfCnpj;
    private String cdClienteCartao;
    private Character idAcao;
}
```

But Spring Data JPA still fails to convert.

Any ideas how I can make this class work for both projection and serialization?

Comment: What is a ‘projection’? I don’t know what the term is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: A projection is used to return only parts of an entity. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections. For example, if you have a users table with a lot of information and only want to retrieve name and email, you can create a class or interface with name and email fields and Spring Data JPA will convert it automatically.

Comment: I see. Thank you for pointing it out, I was not aware of that feature in Spring Data. All I can think of off my head is to use two otherwise identical classes (different annotations only) and let MapStruct do the conversion.